# Gitosis-init returns "Fatal Python error: <stdin> is a directory", why is this?

Tags: python, git, stdin

I'm trying to get gitosis installed because I want to use Indefero and I need a deamon for the git:// protocol. However, following the instructions in the Git Pro book (http://progit.org/book/ch4-7.html) I run into trouble pretty soon. This is what happens:

```
[x@x gitosis]# sudo -H -u git gitosis-init < /tmp/id_dsa.pub
Fatal Python error: <stdin> is a directory
Aborted
```

The error is really vague to me and I didn't find anything helpful around, except that I think stdin is somehow part of C, which confuses me even more since the error is Python. I really don't understand what's going on, or where to look for clues, so I hope someone can tell me where to look next for more info on the problem. Tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitosis is unmaintained and has been deprecated in favor of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) ([progit page](http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html)). Part of the reason for this is because of the extremely error prone installation and setup of gitosis as you have found out.

Addtionally you mention you need a daemon for the git:// protocol. Neither gitosis or gitolite provide this or are necessary for it. Gitolite does provide a way of controlling which repositories are available via the git:// protocol but the external git-daemon needs to already be installed, configured, and running.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'll use gitolite instead then and see if I can install that daemon first than.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your shell is redirecting stdin for sudo, not for your git command. Instead, try running git from a root shell. You (hopefully) can get a root shell with "sudo su -".

Comment: Sorry, replace "root" with "git user" above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:) I'm going to install gitolite though, because of what Arrowmaster said.